# How can I obtain the Trait Slots 4 and 5 in Heroes VI?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I'm still in Silver Rank in HOMM6, and I've unlocked the 2nd and 3rd slots for the traits

The game hints you that there's 5 slots, but the Altar of Wishes doesn't show them

Has anyone been able to acquire them? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

I've reached platinum level and have both DLC packs; there still appears to be no way to purchase the final two dynasty trait slots, so I suspect this is a bug or else they are still reserved for some additional DLC yet to be released.

Answer (score 2):

[Word is](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/605242-might-and-magic-heroes-vi/60792697) (from people who've made it to Platinum) that the game (or the help text) is potentially bugged.

Comment: Sad that this might also be a possibility, while it might be a placeholder for DLC (Like the other answer to this question) the game's state is rather poor, and I wouldn't be surprised if these were blocked due to poor coding.

Answer (score 2):

Those two slots cannot curently be acquired.  Its possible that they will be made available in some DLC or expansion pack.

Comment: It's highly possible considering the current methods developers are using to generate Hype in games, like showing content before it's actually available.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where to find number 4, but you can buy number 5 under Uplay - rewards. There you can buy number 5 for the uplay tokens you get for doing actions in game.